# Filtering resources with different encodings

Tags: maven, encoding

I have a maven project. In `/src/main/resources/` I have two files `foo.properties` and `bar.xml`. The first is encoded in ISO-8859-1 and the second one in UTF-8.

Is there an easy way to get filtering for both files without breaking encoding?

As far as I see, I cannot specify an encoding in a `<resource>` block. It seems only possible to specify an encoding for the plugin itself, but this would lead in both files being filtered using the same encoding.

Ideally I would like to specify something like:

- *.properties -> filter using ISO-8859-1
- *.xml -> filter using UTF-8
- *.pdf -> do not filter
- anything else -> filter using default encoding

This doesn't feel like a very unusual situation, is there an easy way to configure this?

Comment: What is in your case default encoding ? UTF 8 ?

Comment: Yes, in my case the default is UTF8. Generally it would be even fine for me to have everything in UTF8, and only an exception for property files.

Answer (score 2):

First i would suggest to put those resources which are iso based into a different directory like `src/main/iso-resources` and use something like this:

```xml
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <name>Resource Test</name>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
              <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-iso-part</id>
            <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/main/iso-resources/</directory>
                </resource>
              </resources>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep your resources in separate directories you can also keep them in the default directory `src/main/resources` and play with exclusions.
The idea is:

- file extensions that should not be filtered should be added to the default configuration using `nonFilteredFileExtensions`
- let the default execution of the resources plugin process resources with the default encoding
- exclude files that do no use this encoding from the `build/resources` configuration
- for each additional encoding you want to handle, add an execution of goal "copy-resources" with explicit `includes` that selects only the targeted files

This example only handles .properties but you can easily generalize:

```
<resources>
     <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>application*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
 </resources>
```

...

```
   <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                  <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>properties</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>application*.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```